# How can I have smaller db file sizes with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB for storage but the initial db size is around 50MB (even with --smallfiles given to the server at startup).

How can I start off with a much smaller db size (1MB max)?

Comment: "mongo" is short for "humongous". Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why is it a problem? Do you have many databases? Can't you use multiple collections instead of multiple databases.

But there is also commandline option --nssize  (see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters). Have you tried that one?

Comment: --nssize only affects the namespace file that's created for each database. That file is 16MB by default and can be shrunk depending on how many collections you need to be able to accommodate. OP was not including this file in their size estimate. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to specify an initial DB file size. I'd love it if there were.